# why pagination buttons appear vertically?

Tags: python, html, django, pagination

I made these pagination buttons but they appear like this picture and not beneath my posts what should I do? if I need to upload another part of code please let me know

[They look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4Moo.jpg)

welcome.html

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}My Blog{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        {% include 'posts/post.html'%}
    {% endfor%}

    {% if is_paginated %}

     {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
      <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page=1">First</a>
      <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
     {% endif %}

     {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
      {% if page_obj.number == num %}
        <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
      {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
           <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
      {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}

     {% if page_obj.has_next %}
      <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
      <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Last</a>
     {% endif %}

    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```html
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from datetime import datetime
from posts.models import post
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.generic import ListView



# Create your views here.


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = post 
    template_name = 'website/welcome.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 3
```

Comment: Probably, it's because css classes you have in link elements.